# Modifying model in parse

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

Hi this is my first problem with Backbone.js. I spent few hours trying figured out how to rander  from this JSON:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
}
```

IMO I should change it in parse method to:

```
{
  {title: "key1", description: "value1"},
  {title: "key2", description: "value2"},
}
```

so it will be easier to output data as a table with handlebars:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{title}}</td>
  <td>{{description}}</td>
</tr>
```

this is my parse method in model

```
parse : function (response) {
  _.each(response, function (value, key, list) {
    this.set({ "title": key, "description": value });
  }, this);
  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
parse : function (response) {
  var res = [];

  _.each(response, function (value, key, list) {
    res.push({ "title": key, "description": value });
  });

  return {"result": res};
}
```

You can access your model data like this.

```
model.get("result");
```

**Note:**

This is wrong syntax.

```
{
  {title: "key1", description: "value1"},
  {title: "key2", description: "value2"},
}
```

You should put this inside an array.

```
 [
  {title: "key1", description: "value1"},
  {title: "key2", description: "value2"},
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are expecting a list of objects from response, you should be using collection instead of model.

collection parse method can look like

```
 parse:function(resp){
     return _.map(_.keys(resp),function(key){
               return {
                   title:key,
                   description:resp[key]
                 }
           })
 }
```